# err obj detect TF2 model: ImportError: No module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

while creating customer object detection I'm facing an issue on make cmd

```
~/object/models/research/cocoapi/PythonAPI$ make all
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1
```

I tried make, make all, make install even it is same error

Comment: Welcome! please search before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=importerror+no+module+named+numpy

Comment: Hi @nagateja, As the error stat there is no numpy package found. Please install numpy package using `pip install numpy` and try again.